# Removing dot and slash on linux du

Tags: linux, du

How can I remove the `./` on `du` when I do `du` on command line

```
[me@mazaredo 11]# du  --max-depth=1 
96  ./mazaredo
96  ./mazaredo1
1982340 ./mazaredo2
10532   ./mazaredo3
2165964 ./mazaredo4
18764968    ./mazaredo5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you 're looking for the below command

```
du --max-depth=1 | sed s@\./@@g
```

Comment: Hi yes something like this I used du -m --max-depth=1 | sed 's/[./]//g'

Answer (score 1):

I used du -m --max-depth=1 | sed 's/[./]//g'

Thanks for replies!

Comment: Just as a note, if you anyone uses the -h for human readable, this will remove all the '.'s.  So 1.1g becomes 11g.

Best to use sed 's/\.$//' 

Thanks for the answer, it was 99% what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instead need to modify code of `du` command

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking solution in one line, then this will help

```
 du --max-depth=1 | perl -n -e "/\\.\\// && print $\\`.$'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using `tr` command as follows

```
du  --max-depth=1 | tr './' ' '
```